# Disable background until form disappears

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to disable the background windows of my application until the top window is close . Exactly like error message window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you show your new window you need to use the [ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) function - not just the Show function:

```
Window dialogWindow = new Window()
dialogWindow.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through ShowDialog:

```
public void ShowMyDialogBox()
{
   using(var testDialog = new Form2())
   {
      // Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
      if (testDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
      {
         // Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox.
         this.txtResult.Text = testDialog.TextBox1.Text;
      }
      else
      {
         this.txtResult.Text = "Cancelled";
      }
   }
}
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx)